# economy mode active engine cranks but wont start

Tags: cranks-wont-run, citroen, picasso

citroen Picasso xsara 1.6 hdi 2004. economy mode active light come up on dash.now engine wont start any ideas would be great. thanks

Comment: By "won't start," do you mean the starter doesn't turn the engine over, or do you mean the starter turns the engine over but the engine doesn't start running?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your battery is too low.
Try charging it up or with another battery/cables.

EDIT :

Economy mode is activated when the car detects an energy drain.
Either you left the CDplayer on for more than 30 minutes without the engine turning or you left your car door open for more than 45 minutes OR battery voltage is too low.

Well, to deactivate the economy mode, in theory, you're supposed to turn on the engine, shut it down and turn it on again.

Since the engine is not turning, I'm guessing it is a battery issue.
Anyway, for any battery issue, the first thing should always be to charge your battery to eliminate the most common problem. :)

Comment: I'm really not sure how you came up with that assessment? Could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Just answered in the initial post.

Comment: The OP is stating the engine will crank, but won't start/run. I'm still not sure how your explanation describes the situation, though charging the battery won't hurt anything.

Comment: I see we both read more than we should. I don't see any information about cranking or not  in "now engine wont start any ideas".